# Sql view that shows latest + creates row for first day if not present in dataset

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-view

I have the following data:

```
Date Store Product Price
d1   s1    p1      0
d1   s1    p2      0
d1   s2    p1      0
d2   s1    p1      0
...
```

So, millions of rows of data with store-product pairs which have a price for a certain date.
I would like to create a view that gives me that last X days of data. Easy with something like:

```
SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE date > DATEADD(day, -X, GETDATE())
```

But I also need to make sure that I actually have an entry for all X days for each store-product pair. So, if at today-X days there is not entry for a certain store and product pair, I need to find the latest price for that pair (if it exists) and then duplicate that price into a row with date = today - X. Does this make sense?

Comment: we really need more informations. Are your `store` and `product` items stored in another table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question as I see it then for this sample data

```
CREATE TABLE t1
    ([Date] DATE, [Store] varchar(2), [Product] varchar(2), [Price] int)
;

INSERT INTO t1
    ([Date], [Store], [Product], [Price])
VALUES
    ('20180525', 's1', 'p3', 0),
    ('20180601', 's1', 'p1', 0),
    ('20180602', 's1', 'p2', 0),
    ('20180603', 's2', 'p1', 0),
    ('20180604', 's1', 'p1', 0)
;

DECLARE @NumOfDays INT = 10
```

The OP wants to show `('20180525', 's1', 'p3', 0)` row as this is before `DATEADD( DAY, -@NumOfDays, GETDATE())` days ago

So try this solution

```
SELECT
     --T.Date
     [Date] = CAST(DATEADD( DAY, -@NumOfDays, GETDATE()) AS DATE)
    ,T.Store
    ,T.Product
    ,T.Price
FROM dbo.t1 T
INNER JOIN(
    SELECT Mxdate = MAX(T2.Date), T2.Store, T2.Product
    FROM dbo.t1 T2
    GROUP BY T2.Store, T2.Product
) MxDate ON MxDate.Product = T.Product AND MxDate.Store = T.Store
WHERE MxDate.Mxdate < DATEADD( DAY, -@NumOfDays, GETDATE())
UNION
SELECT
     T3.Date
    ,T3.Store
    ,T3.Product
    ,T3.Price
FROM dbo.t1 T3
WHERE T3.Date > DATEADD( DAY, -@NumOfDays, GETDATE())
```

Output

```
Date        Store   Product Price
2018-05-27  s1      p3      0       --this is the row before the daterange
2018-06-01  s1      p1      0
2018-06-02  s1      p2      0
2018-06-03  s2      p1      0
2018-06-04  s1      p1      0
```

Comment: I'm glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

I would start from left-to-right, i mean:

build a calendar for your date range -> build (if you dont have one) a list for each product-store combination -> then join those 2 datasets with your actual table and the rest should be easy.

Check this approach:

```
DECLARE @MinDate DATE = DATEADD(DAY, -5, CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE())),
        @MaxDate DATE = CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE())

SELECT  DISTINCT
        MYDATES.DATE,
        MYDATES.STORE,
        MYDATES.PRODUCT,
        --GET LATEST PRICE FOR THE COUPLE PRODUCT-STORE IF THERE IS NOONE IN SELECTED DATE
        CASE    WHEN T.PRICE IS NULL
                THEN (  SELECT MAX(T1.PRICE)
                        FROM MYTAB T1
                        WHERE T1.STORE = MYDATES.STORE
                        AND T1.PRODUCT = MYDATES.PRODUCT
                        AND T1.DATE = ( SELECT MAX(DATE)
                                        FROM MYTAB T2
                                        WHERE T2.PRODUCT = MYDATES.PRODUCT
                                        AND T2.STORE = MYDATES.STORE))
                ELSE T.PRICE END AS PRICE, 
        CASE    WHEN T.PRICE IS NULL
                THEN 'RECOVERED FROM ' + (  SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR, MAX(DATE), 103)
                                        FROM MYTAB T2
                                        WHERE T2.PRODUCT = MYDATES.PRODUCT
                                        AND T2.STORE = MYDATES.STORE)
                ELSE ''
                END AS [PRICE FROM]

FROM (SELECT * FROM STOREANDPRODSOURCE SP, 
(SELECT TOP (DATEDIFF(DAY, @MinDate, @MaxDate) + 1)
        Date = DATEADD(DAY, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY a.object_id) - 1, @MinDate)
FROM    sys.all_objects a
        CROSS JOIN sys.all_objects b) D ) MYDATES
LEFT JOIN MYTAB T ON CONVERT(DATE, T.DATE) = MYDATES.DATE
                     AND T.PRODUCT = MYDATES.PRODUCT
                     AND T.STORE = MYDATES.STORE
```

Check [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/6010c/2) too